# How to do Authorization redirect on ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

So, I come from a ASP.NET 2.0 WebForms background and am new to ASP.NET MVC which I find it wonderful, however, i've been somewhat accostumed to it.

This time, my problem has to do with Authentication and Authorization Model:

I used to restrict folders via Web.config's authorization section

```
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
        <!--
        <allow users="*"/>
  -->
    </authorization>
```

So when a user tries to access a private "page" be redirected to index page; How can I do this on MVC?
I used to save the user id (or object) in the session data... now I don't know how or where to store it, in a MVC'ish way.

As a side note, my data model has a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE user_perm (
    user INT,
    feature INT,
)
```

And I would like to restrict access to certain controllers based on the content of this table. Ho w can I achieve it?

PS: i'm aware of these other questions, but they refer to beta version and I'm unsure if yet apply to the  current released version.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please see my answer, you should be able to modify the RequiresRole attribute to match your specific requirement for allowing access.

Answer (score 3):

You should try attribute filtering on controller actions. (See [this](http://codeclimber.net.nz/archive/2009/04/08/13-asp.net-mvc-extensibility-points-you-have-to-know.aspx) link for good information.)

Controller actions point you to actual 'pages', you should secure those.

What I use (custom attribute...):

```
Public Class ProjectController
    Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

    <Models.Authentication.RequiresAuthentication()> _
    Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult

    End Function

    <Models.Authentication.RequiresRole(Role:="Admin")> _
    Function Delete(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult

    End Function
End Class
```

And the authorization attribute:

```
Namespace Models.Authentication
    Public Class RequiresAuthenticationAttribute : Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
        Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(ByVal filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)
            If Not filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
                Dim redirectOnSuccess As String = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
                Dim redirectUrl As String = String.Format("?ReturnUrl={0}", redirectOnSuccess)
                Dim loginUrl As String = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + redirectUrl

                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, True)
            End If
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class RequiresRoleAttribute : Inherits ActionFilterAttribute
        Private _role As String

        Public Property Role() As String
            Get
                Return Me._role
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                Me._role = value
            End Set
        End Property

        Public Overrides Sub OnActionExecuting(ByVal filterContext As System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext)
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Me.Role) Then
                If Not filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated Then
                    Dim redirectOnSuccess As String = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.AbsolutePath
                    Dim redirectUrl As String = String.Format("?ReturnUrl={0}", redirectOnSuccess)
                    Dim loginUrl As String = FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl + redirectUrl

                    filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(loginUrl, True)
                Else
                    Dim hasAccess As Boolean = filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole(Me.Role)
                    If Not hasAccess Then
                        Throw New UnauthorizedAccessException("You don't have access to this page. Only " & Me.Role & " can view this page.")
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                Throw New InvalidOperationException("No Role Specified")
            End If

        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: Sorry, i go way back on VB :). I really like C# / Javascript constructs and really HATE the line continuation mark _ for VB. But VB is perfectly readable to me. Hurray for intellisense hehe

Answer (score 2):

use the Authorize attribute. You can place it on individual actions or on the entire controller.

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
```

More information here:

http://forums.asp.net/p/1428467/3192831.aspx

Comment: And how to do it based on the user_perm table? should I inherit Authorize?

Comment: You should build a custom attribute. Please see my answer with the custom attribute example....

Comment: Yeah I use my own custom attribute for my stuff - check out ropstah's example.

Answer (score 1):

They way we are handling it is through Attributes.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult SomeAction() {
        return View();
    }
```

“[Authorize]” is equvalent to “[Authorize(Roles="user")]”. For specific roles use [Authorize(Roles="")].